# How can I Solve a 0-1 Multi(constraint/dimensional) Knapsack Problem?

Tags: java, python, algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have a 5 bag and 200 items with values. The issue is that each item has a different weight on a different bag, and all bags have different capacities.

```
For bag example:
Bag 1 capacity = 500
Bag 2 capacity = 200
etc....

For item example:
Item 1 weight for = bag1:50, bag2:70, bag3:15 etc...
Item 2 weight for = bag1:1, bag2: 90, ......
etc....
```

Each bag must have the same item inside of them. So if I put the item 1 to the bag1, I have to put that item to the other bags, so the capacity of any bag must not be passed.
How can I find the maximum value items that can be inside of these bags? What should I search or how can I solve that? I researched a lot but could not find an understable solution or a code.

A sample data with constraints is here:

```
num of knapsacks = 2
knapsack1 capacity = 600
knapsack2 capacity = 500
num of items = 28

values of each item:
1898 440 22507 270 14148 3100 4650 30800 615 4975 1160 4225 510 11880 479 440 490 330 110 560 24355 2885 11748 4550 750 3720 1950 10500

item weights for knapsack1 (in same order with item values)
45 0 85 150 65 95 30 0 170 0 40 25 20 0 0 25 0 0 25 0 165 0 85 0 0 0 0 100

item weights for knapsack2
30 20 125 5 80 25 35 73 12 15 15 40 5 10 10 12 10 9 0 20 60 40 50 36 49 40 19 150
```

The itemset that satisfies the sample data is:

```
Sum of values = 138821
Values: 1898 22507 14148 3100 4650 30800 4975 11880 490 24355 11748 4550 3720
```

Comment: Integer programming is a decent starting point, e.g., http://www.math.clemson.edu/~mjs/courses/mthsc.440/integer.pdf

Comment: What d u mean by "if I put the item 1 to the bag1, I have to put that item to the other bags," ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ Like a normal knapsack problem, each item can either be selected, or skipped. If the item is selected, its weight is added to every bag. In the example, if item 1 is selected, then 50 is added to bag 1, 70 is added to bag 2, and 15 is added to bag 3. But, if item 1 is skipped, then it isn't added to any bag. You can't select item 1 for bag 3 only.

Comment: Then this is not a coding question.. neither it is asking how to code an established algorithm.. | imho, https://math.stackexchange.com/ serves better for this kind of question. | "researched a lot but could not find an understable solution or a code." I think.. bcoz it is STILL an open research topic. If u r doing this for MSc/PhD, full literature research & algorithm comparison is worth while.. | My take : just need to code 1.. put a trail value (of items and bag).. then repeat the process. The good news is.. it is not actually easy for others to say "a better solution is around" to you. ( :

Comment: @p._phidot_ I could not take the your advise about coding :D Do you have idea about full steps?

Comment: If you have the full requirement (not just "for bag/item example.. etc....") and the constrain listed, edit the question with that info (include ur trails) and post it.

Comment: @p._phidot_ I updated the question with a sample.

Comment: nice edit.. this question look way better than the 1st version.. | btw.. hope this [ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/0-1-knapsack-problem-dp-10/) is useful.. /(^_^)

Comment: @p._phidot_ the ref is about one knapsacks, doesnt give any idea for my problem

Comment: I share the link to answer the `could not find .. a code` part.. ( :

Comment: (this bothered me inside..) How does `138821` fit into `600 + 500` bags?

Comment: @p._phidot_ gather the values and weigths of these items (1,3,5,6,7,8,10,14,17,21,23,24,26) and you can see the sum of values is 138821 and their sum of weights dont cross the corresponding bags weight.

Comment: `each item` in "5 bag and 200 items with values" example is the terminology used to explain `value` in the "2nd example".. right? (imho, item <> value)